# How to place a pointer or a image at a given latitude and longitude

Tags: android

here is the code which iam using

```
                      String geoUri=String.format("geo:%f,%f?z=10",latitude,longitude);
                       Uri geo=Uri.parse(geoUri);

                       Intent geomap=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,geo);
                       startActivity(geomap);
```

this is hust taking me to the locattion but i want a pointer or image at given latitude and longitude..how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I use an ItemizedOverlay for the purpose:

```
mapItemizedOverlay.addOverlayItem(new OverlayItem(new GeoPoint (
    (int) (latitude * 1E6), (int) (longitude * 1E6)), "title", "info"));
```